# Cumulative array aggregation in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataset

| event_id | user_id | event | event_type | event_ts | item_id | next_event_type | next_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1000,"user_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_PURCHASED"} | ITEM_PURCHASED | 5260 | 1000 | ITEM_PURCHASED | 1001 |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1001,"user_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_PURCHASED"} | ITEM_PURCHASED | 5855 | 1001 | ITEM_PURCHASED | 1002 |

I want to cumulatively append the next `item_id` to the array. I know I can do this in a udf, but the dataset is quite massive and want to avoid a performance hit.

| event_id | user_id | event | event_type | event_ts | item_id | next_event_type | next_item_id | next_item_set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1000,"user_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_PURCHASED"} | ITEM_PURCHASED | 5260 | 1000 | ITEM_PURCHASED | 1001 | [1000, 1001] |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1001,"user_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_PURCHASED"} | ITEM_PURCHASED | 5855 | 1001 | ITEM_PURCHASED | 1002 | [1000, 1001, 1002] |

This is the query I have so far

```
with a as (
select event_id
    , user_id
    , event
    , event_type
    , event_ts
    , item_id
    , lead(event_type) over (partition by user_id order by event_ts) as next_event_type
    , lead(item_id) over (partition by user_id order by event_ts) as next_item_id
from tableA
)
select *
, concat(lag(next_item_set) over (order by event_ts), array(next_item_id))  as cumulative_item_set
from a
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `collect_list` or `collect_set` and specify the window's frame from `unbounded preceding` to `1 following`. Try adding this to your select clause (SparkSQL):

```
collect_list(item_id) over (partition by user_id order by event_ts rows between unbounded preceding and 1 following) as next_item_set
```